# Create points with planar location data

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, azimuth

Slightly confused. I need to add 3 point features to an already created map project (state plane projection). The description given to me about the location of the points is the planar location, so no matter what I try and use as the display unit, nothing will work for finding planar x,y coords. Do I need to create a new map project with an Azmiuthal-Equadistant projection and create the points there, then import them into the premade map or am I missing something very simple?

Comment: What GIS software do you use? What coordinate system / projection are the points in? Can you give an example?

Comment: You mention of display units makes me think you're using ArcGIS. Put the points in an Excel or text file (header: ID,x,y,attribute). Use Add X,Y data (File, Add Data). In that dialog, set the coordinate system to the AE pcs of the points. Once the XY layer is added, you can then export to a shapefile or gdb feature class if you want.

Comment: Using ArcGIS 10.2. The pre-existing shapefile I am trying to add the three points to are in State Plane Florida West 0902. As for the three points I've been given, the write up just says Planar Location and gives an easting and a northing. An example: you have a layer of fire hydrants in State Plane Proj, someone tells you it is missing three and gives you a .pdf that lists the Easting and Northing of the three new hydrants. No other information provided except for attributes of those hydrants.